# How can I get a 64 bit USB driver to load in Vista 64

Tags: drivers, signing, vista64

I am working in Vista 64 bit system.

I have a 3rdPartyUsbDriver.sys and 3rdPartyUsbDriver.inf files.

I have made the neccesary changes to the vendor & product IDs in the inf file, to work with my custom hardware. This installs and works in 'Unsigned Driver Test mode' just fine.

I now want to install this driver in 'Normal mode'. I do not care, if it pops up warnings that this driver is from a untrusted source.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to create and sign a 'cat' file based in the .inf and .sys file.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to install the driver on Vista 4 bit is to [digitally sign](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/winlogo/drvsign/kmsigning.mspx) the driver. 
I think that you need to get the signature [here](http://www.verisign.com/). 
I'm not 100% sure but the driver might need to pass [WHQL](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/whql/default.mspx) as well. WHQL Policies page located [here](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/whql/policies/default.mspx).
If it's possible contact your driver vendor and ask him to do it.